# Syncing up Core Data with a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I know this is probably a pretty basic question, but I'm working with Core Data and a UITableView. I import all the data from Core Data to various mutable arrays. When a user rearranges the items in the table, it's easy enough to swap the items in the mutable arrays I obtained from core data earlier, but is there an easy way to sync the new mutable array with the existing core data? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is actually how to persist the **order** of the data in your table view rows in Core Data.

The answer is you have to introduce a new integer / `NSNumber` attribute to keep track. I have done this in a simple app managing a to-do list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `NSFetchedResultsController`. It greatly simplifies using a table view and Core Data together. No need worrying about intermediary arrays.

Comment: I am using them. That's what I use to get the data from Core Data to the array. Can you explain what you mean? Clearly I don't have a huge understanding of Core Data yet.

Comment: Set the fetchedResultsController as self. You can then use these 'content changed' callbacks to update the tableView. Look at this tutorial for more information: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Answer (score 1):

Lion [added support](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010355-SW34) for ordered to-many relationships, which is much easier than storing the indices within the entities. If you're targeting Lion you can mark the relationship **Ordered** and access it using a new class [NSOrderedSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which will persist its order, like an array.

Comment: Is this available in iOS 5? (I know it's under a NDA...)

Comment: Looks like it. The `NSOrderedSet.h` that ships with Xcode 4.1 says `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0)`.